# Binary is being spit out as Hexadecimal value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have made a quite a few Googling but unfortunately, I could not find a definitive answer for my question.

Please see the following simple query;

```
DECLARE @Bin binary(3) = 754645
Select @Bin
```

Even though the variable type is binary, it is being spit out as a hexadecimal value. I just would like to know why.

My thinking is that, it is probably to save from space based on how SQL Server stores the data. Please let me know your thoughts.

Thanks.

Comment: In what format were you *expecting* the decimal number 754645 to be represented when stored in binary?

Comment: Well, based on the variable name, I would expect 0s and 1s. But it spits out, 0x0B83D5 which seems to be hexadecimal value of the variable.

Comment: In which case, related: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19963/why-hex-octal-or-hexadecimal-computers-use-binary-and-humans-decimals

Comment: for 0 and 1 you have to define `bit`

Comment: @tinka op meant many 1s and 0s (100101010).

Comment: @tinka, bit would not store that large of a data.It can store only 1s and 0s.

Comment: Hex is a convenient way for computers to represent binary data. each hex block is 4 binary bits. Im guessing sql binary data is stored in 4 bit blocks

Comment: @Jamiec, thats the answer I was looking for! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hexdecimal is just a easy way represent binary data.  So SQL Server is just printing it as hex to make it easy for you, but it is still stored as binary.

Answer (score 1):

Your select statement returned the raw binary data to whatever client you were using to connect to your SQL Server. The client decided to display the binary data in hex.